# OSM: Getting the correct Overpass Turbo query using a keyword (and values)

Tags: openstreetmap, data, query, overpass-api

I'm completely new to Overpass queries for getting OSM data, so sorry for this maybe trivial question.

I'm looking for the correct query using Overpass turbo. I have found some demo queries, but I am not sure if they are correct for my needs, so I would like to be sure.

My aim is to get all Points of Interests, which are using the KEY: "tourism" in a specified region (a bounding box with geographic coordinates, or a specified district, like a country).

I know I can get all data in a specified region with this query:

```
(node(51.249,7.148,51.251,7.152);<;);out meta;
```

but how do i include the keyword, that only POIs with they key: tourism are returned?

2nd question: how could i expand this query to receive only specific values of the tourism key, like all apartments, viewpoints and attractions (values: "apartment", "viewpoint", "attraction") in one file?

More information for tourism key:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:tourism

Answer (score 5):

In overpass turbo, click on "Wizard", enter `tourism=*` in the search field and then click on "build and run query" to execute your query.

You may of course navigate to your area of interest and hit the "Run" button to re-run the query.

For the second part of your question, simply enter the following in the wizard popup:

`tourism=apartment or tourism=viewpoint or tourism=attraction`